# How make PhoneGap app *not* full screen

Tags: cordova-3

I tried setting the fullscreen preference to 'false' but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Also, is 'fullscreen' the word I want? I just want to be able to see that status bar and be able to pull down notifications from within my app.

Using PhoneGap 3.0.0

Comment: would you be able to elaborate with some sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your *main Activity*.
Probably the layout of your `Activity` is configured so that the `WebView` occupy the entire screen, change it to a `LinearLayout` in it and add one title bar and just below your `WebView`.

See more at:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved re-installing the whole phonegap app (using the QR code) and not simply updating the app.